# Open the windows phone 8 windows calender through c# code

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, calendar

I would like to open the windows 8 calender through c# code once a button is pressed by the user. Is it possible to open the calender? and if so how can this be achieved?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Windows Phone application that has a page with a button named ButtonAppointments.

```
 private void ButtonAppointments_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Appointments appts = new Appointments();

        //Identify the method that runs after the asynchronous search completes.
        appts.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<AppointmentsSearchEventArgs>(Appointments_SearchCompleted);

        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime end = start.AddDays(7);
        int max = 20;

        //Start the asynchronous search.
        appts.SearchAsync(start, end, max, "Appointments Test #1");
    }

    void Appointments_SearchCompleted(object sender, AppointmentsSearchEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something with the results.
        MessageBox.Show(e.Results.Count().ToString());
    }
```

Refered from : [`How to access calendar data for Windows Phone 8`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286421%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Hay budy! what is this "Appointment", Is this Subject of Appointments...?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private void ButtonAppointments_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Appointments appts = new Appointments();

        appts.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<AppointmentsSearchEventArgs>(Appointments_SearchCompleted);

        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime end = start.AddDays(7);
        int max = 10;

        //Start the asynchronous search.
        appts.SearchAsync(start, end, max, "Appointment");
    }
```

Comment: Hay budy! what is this "Appointment", Is this Subject of Appointments...?

Answer (score 1):

Also add this to display the results

```
MessageBox.Show(e.Results.Count().ToString());
```